# Installing skype on 64-bit breaks on dpkg --add-architecture i386

Tags: 64-bit, skype

It is supposed to be easy process:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

But on the first line `dpkg --add-architecture i386` I get an error

```
dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !
```

How to solve this so that I can finally install Skype?

**EDIT**

In synaptic I get error `The following packages have unmet dependencies:skype: Depends: skype-bin but it is a virtual package`

If I try to install skype-bin, I get error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt4-xml:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: sni-qt:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: @Braiam Solved by changing repository server to main one (instead of my country's one). Unbelievable!!!!!

Comment: You can mark [yours](http://askubuntu.com/a/381725/22949) as the accepted answer now, by clicking the gray check mark to the left of it. This will turn that check mark green and make even clearer to others with this problem that you were able to solve it and what solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get stuck try changing server to "Main server" instead of your country's servers. When I did this, Skype installed flawlessly from the Software Center.

Comment: I would blame that your country server doesn't have the `i386` packages. Can you add it for future reference?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "Can you add it for future reference"?

Comment: This does not solve the problem for me... Seems that the i386 packages libqtwebkit4:i386 and libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 are still missing.